# Can any computable real number be represented as the sum of some integer plus some rational number times some other computable real number?

Tags: real-numbers, computability

It's known that imaginary numbers can be expressed as vectors such as $\alpha + \beta i$. My question is: Can you represent a [computable real number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) with a similar algebraic definition?

For example does there exist some constants such that:

$$e =\alpha + \beta \sqrt{2}$$

Where $\alpha \in\Bbb{Z}$ and $\beta \in\Bbb{Q}$ and $e$ is Euler's number.

Computable reals are things that can be approached arbitrarily closely by an infinite sequence of rational numbers so is it possible to express any computable real in this way?

Comment: Presumably you want to fix the irrational number say $a$, and then write $c=n(c)+q(c) a$ where $n(c) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $q(c) \in \mathbb{Q}$. But this is not possible, because there are computable irrational numbers within $1$ of each other which are not rational multiples of one another. Probably the easiest way to show this is to pick $c$ transcendental (if $a$ is algebraic) or algebraic (if $c$ is transcendental).

Comment: If you mean Euler's constant : This number is transcendental, so cannot be represented as desired. In the case of the Euler-Mascheroni-constant (not likely the intent of the question) : it is open whether it is even irrational.

Comment: The title and the text statements are different. In the title question you can use the integer "0" and the rational as "1". And your definition of *computable* seems fishy because every real can be approximated be an infinite sequence of rationals.

Comment: @gammatester: Not all such infinite sequences of rationals are computable, though.

Comment: I read on wikipedia that e, euler's constant, was computable which is why I chose it. I know that the square root of 2 is computable by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a *single* computable number that you can use to decompose *all* computable reals in that way.

You can't even have any *finite* number of "basis elements", even if you allow arbitrary rational functions of the basis elements rather than just the integer/rational combinations you describe.

This is because there exists a sequence of infinitely many *algebraically independent* computable numbers -- such as $$e^e, e^{e^2}, e^{e^3}, e^{e^4}, \ldots$$
thanks to the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem. So the field of computable reals has transcendence degree $\aleph_0$ over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Does this extend to all transcendental numbers or are their some transcendentals for which there is some partial notion of decomposability, even if it is limited?